# Does android browser support automatic message processing from any custom server?

Tags: android, browser, notifications, message

Is it possible to send a message via any channel to an Android device, such that it results in a notification being posted on the Android notification bar. When the user clicks on this item, a URL (mentioned in the  received message) is opened in the browser. The trick is, that I do not want to install any client application on the android device.

Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK This is not possible. Android Browser does not support posting of notification when you navigate to a website

Comment: I didnt ask for posting notification when the user browses a page. Rather I want to know if it is possible for the device (or some in-build app in android,like browser) to receive a message with a URL from some server(custom), post a notification in the notification bar such that tapping on the notification item opens a browser window with the above URL!

Comment: So you want some app to show a notification which when clicked will open the browser?

Comment: yes, some app which is a part of android. For instance the browser itself, or some platform service listening to such events which have been authorized by the user.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible! No such feature come as a part of android.